# Computing the integral $I=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^{\pi}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions

Let $I=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^{\pi}}dx$ If we use $u=x^{\pi}$ then we get $dx=\frac{du}{\pi^{\frac{\pi-1}{\pi}}}$ are there any better identites or substitution that can make integral easier to compute?

Comment: This integral has no close form expression.

Comment: The  indefinite integral, does not have a closed form, to solve it you must surely use the hypergeometric function. On the definite integral, only one observation: In general, you can prove that $$\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^{n}}\operatorname{dx}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{2\Gamma\left( \frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{n}\right)}, \quad n>0.$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**[Note]** : *You can use the beta function* :

- Beta Function : $\displaystyle \mathfrak{B}(x,y):=\int_{0}^{1}(1-\mu)^{x-1}\mu^{y-1}\;\text{d}\mu=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$

Let $\mu:=x^{\pi}$. Then :
\begin{align*}
x^{\pi}=\mu&\implies\text{d}\mu=\pi x^{\pi -1}\\ \\
&\iff\text{d}x=\frac{\text{d}\mu}{\pi\cdot\mu^{\displaystyle\frac{\pi-1}{\pi}}} =\frac{1}{\pi}\mu^{\displaystyle\frac{1-\pi}{\pi}}\text{d}\mu
\end{align*}
Therefore :
\begin{align*}
I&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1-\mu}\cdot\mu^{\displaystyle\frac{1-\pi}{\pi}}\text{d}\mu\\ \\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}(1-\mu)^{\frac{3}{2}-1}\mu^{\frac{1}{\pi}-1}\;\text{d}\mu\\ \\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\mathfrak{B}\left(\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{\pi}\right)\\ \\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi}\right)}\\ \\
&\approx 0.846941\cdots
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

*Just for the fun of it*

As said in comments and answers, the is no closed form expression for the antiderivative. However, we could have an infinite series representation of it since
$$\sqrt{1-x^{\pi}}=\sqrt{1-x^{3}}\Bigg[1+x^3\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac { 1} {2^n\, n! }\left(\frac{\log (x)}{x^3-1}\right)^n P_n(x)\,(\pi-3)^n\Bigg] $$ where the first $P_n(x)$ are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n(x) \\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & x^3-2 \\
 3 & x^6-2 x^3+4 \\
 4 & x^9-4 x^6-4 x^3-8 \\
 5 & x^{12}-4 x^9+36 x^6+56 x^3+16 \\
 6 & x^{15}-6 x^{12}-76 x^9-496 x^6-336 x^3-32 \\
 7 & x^{18}-6 x^{15}+288 x^{12}+3088 x^9+5328 x^6+1632 x^3+64
\end{array}
\right)$$

For any $n$, each term shows an explicit antiderivative in terms of hypergeometric function. For example, for $n=1$
$$\int \frac{ x^3 \log (x)}{ \sqrt{1-x^3}}\,dx=$$
$$-\frac{x^4}{16}  \left(\,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{4}{3},\frac{4}{3};\frac{7}{3},\frac{7}{3};x^3\right)-
   4 \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{4}{3};\frac{7}{3};x^3\right) \log (x)\right)$$

Using only the elements given in this answer, computing the integral from $0$ to $t$ gives the following results

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 t & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} & \text{error} \\
 0.1 & 0.099991285257983 & 0.099991285257855 & 1.29 \times 10^{-13}\\
 0.2 & 0.199846061391490 & 0.199846061391227 & 2.63 \times 10^{-13}\\
 0.3 & 0.299172693249054 & 0.299172693248698 & 3.56 \times 10^{-13}\\
 0.4 & 0.397263323235192 & 0.397263323234765 & 4.26 \times 10^{-13}\\
 0.5 & 0.493045151618189 & 0.493045151617706 & 4.83 \times 10^{-13}\\
 0.6 & 0.584997454713703 & 0.584997454713173 & 5.30 \times 10^{-13}\\
 0.7 & 0.670989777542907 & 0.670989777542338 & 5.70 \times 10^{-13}\\
 0.8 & 0.747926304221105 & 0.747926304220506 & 6.00 \times 10^{-13}\\
 0.9 & 0.810765563739254 & 0.810765563738633 & 6.20 \times 10^{-13}\\
 1.0 & 0.846941809210854 & 0.846941809208595 & 2.26 \times 10^{-12}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Otherwise and much simpler (but more difficult to compute)
$$I=\int\sqrt{1-x^{\pi}}\,dx=\frac{x \left(\pi  \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{\pi };1+\frac{1}{\pi };x^{\pi
   }\right)+2 \sqrt{1-x^{\pi }}\right)}{2+\pi }$$